# Adding a dynamically created div to another div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating two divs:

```
var div_day=document.createElement("div");
var div_dateValue=document.createElement("div");
```

I then want to add div_day to an existing calendar div and div_dateValue to div_day:

```
$('#calendar').append(div_day)                          
$(div_day).append(div_dateValue);
```

div_day gets added to calendar, but div_dateValue does not get added to div_day, and the script stops there.  No errors in the console but it is in a loop and should have more div_days (each with a unique id).  I am new to jquery so any help is appreciated.

In my search I have found how to add divs, but not to add a dynamically created div to another dynamically created div.

Thanks for your help!

Kevin

Comment: Have you tried creating your `div` tags using jQuery from the very beginning?  `var div_day = $("<div>").html("Tuesday");`  I'm not entirely sure what your problem is without seeing more code, but it's a thought...

Comment: If you c/p'd as is, you're missing a semicolon after the first line

Comment: @tkm256 Semicolon would not cause this problem because of the carriage return after the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div_day.appendChild(div_dateValue)
$('#calendar').append(div_day)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something else must be going on (even with your missing semi-colon).  Your example works fine here:

http://jsfiddle.net/P4rh5/

But, instead of creating divs with straight javascript, you can do it with jQuery:

```
var div_day = $("<div>");
var div_dateValue = $("<div>");

$('#calendar').append(div_day);                        
$(div_day).append(div_dateValue);
```

Of course, you could do this in a single step:

```
$('#calendar').append("<div><div></div></div>");
```

Comment: so if I was setting a bunch of div settings, I would just do it in line?

such as:
div_day = $("<div id='blah' style='etc etc etc'>");

Comment: `div_day = $( "<div>" ).css( 'color', 'red' ).css( 'width', '10px' ).etc`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div><div></div></div>').appendTo("#calendar");
```

Try this and mark it as answer if it helps